# Moving people and goods between spinning and non-spinning parts of a space station

Tags: technology, hard-science, space-travel, space-constructs

I'm thinking of three possibilities - all of which have the user experience of elevators and don't require space suits.

1. involves a programmed pod that moves a short distance in space between docking on rotating to non-rotating docks.
2. involves hollow struts on the rotating part that a pod would be timed to pod into or back from the non-rotating center
3. pods roll across the outside of the strut/hub interface like something that can hinge on either side.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What is your worldbuilding problem?

Comment: The usual method described in sci-fi is a central spindle, perpendicular to rotation, with a docking port between that and the rotating section mated via a rotation-friendly hub (eg, circular and using ball bearings). Goods could then be lowered down the rotating portion via elevator.  Is there some reason this canonical scheme doesn't work for your needs?

Comment: There is a Youtube video which demonstrates the various types of docking systems on a rotating station. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4pmFz06oZHA